# How to redirect printing from screen (or any FILE*) into a string/char* in C++

Tags: c++, file, char

I am working on a C++ code and I wish to do the following:

In the code there is a new type, T, there is a method defined on T that prints some information to a type FILE* variable.

I would like to do some work on this string inside of the program, so I would like to have a variable of type string (or even char*) that will contain what is printed to the screen (if I give the printing function stdout as the File*).

How can I do this ? maybe I can create some FILE* variable and then create (somehow) a string/char* variable with the information that is stored in that File* variable we created ?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For which OS it should work?

Comment: What is `File`? How is it defined? Or you mean `FILE` from C's `stdio.h` header?

Comment: @Sergey - My mistake, it is FILE. I will edit. thanks for pointing this out to me!

Comment: Can you change the implementation of `T`? Then you could use a `std::ostream&` instead of a `FILE*` and pass a `std::ostringstream` as parameter.

Comment: @FlorianSowade - This is not my code so I am unaware of who is using this print method (so changing the type may cause others problems).
I can, however, create a duplicate of this method (with a different name) and change the type there - but this also means I have to actually change how this method is implemented, right ? If I do do this then how does this help me to create the string/char* I want ? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

POSIX 1.2008 `fmemopen`, `open_memstream` functions create a `FILE*` pointer which writes to (and/or reads from) memory.

If it does not work for your platform (and there is no other way to hook into `FILE *`), then you're out of luck.

The next thing I'd try is creating an anonymous pipe, (POSIX `pipe`, Windows `CreatePipe`), wrapping its writing side into `FILE *` (POSIX `fdopen`, plus Windows `_open_osfhandle` to get a CRT fd from HANDLE). Here you have to ensure that the pipe's buffer size is enough, *or* to spawn a thread for reading the pipe. Don't forget to `fflush` the writing side after the method is done (or use `setbuf` to disable buffering).

Comment: How does reading/writing from memory helps me ? I do not understand...sorry for the lack of knowledge. Also, this should be platform-independent

Comment: You open a `FILE*` writing to memory, make that method write to that `FILE*`, then you close the `FILE*` and... have your `char*` in memory. And it's *very* platform-dependent. (Pipes are platform-dependent too, but more portable -- even with additional reader thread).

Answer (score 1):

There are several platform-independent ways to do it.
In C++ you can use `stringstream(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)`, which has many `<<` operator overloads. So if you pass a reference to `ostream&` (not `oFstream`) to the output method, you can easily switch between files, stadard output stream and string outputs, because all this streams are inherited from ostream. Then you can get `std::string` object from `stringstream` and get C-string from it if you need.

Code example:

Output function (or method, then you don't need the second argument from the example):

```cpp
void PrintMyObjectToSomeStream(std::ostream& stream, const MyClass& obj)
{
    stream << obj.pubField1;
    stream << obj.pubField2;
    stream << obj.GetPrivField1();
    stream << "string literal";
    stream << obj.GetPrivField2();
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
MyClass obj1;
std::ofsstream ofs;
std::stringstream sstr;
//...open file for ofs, check if it is opened and so on...
//...use obj1, fill it's member fields with actual information...
PrintMyObjectToSomeStream(obj1,std::cout);//print to console
PrintMyObjectToSomeStream(obj1,sstr);//print to stringstream
PrintMyObjectToSomeStream(obj1,ofs);//print to file

std::string str1=sstr.str();//get std::string from stringstream
char* sptr1=sstr.str().c_str();//get pointer to C-string from stringstream
```

Or you can overload `operator<<`:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const MyClass& obj)
{
    stream << obj1.pubField;
    //...and so on
    return stream;
}
```

then you can use it in this way:

```cpp
MyClass obj2;
int foo=100500;
std::stringstream sstr2;
std::ofstream ofs;//don't forget to open it

//print to stringstream
sstr2 << obj2 << foo << "string lineral followed by int\n";
//here you can get std::string or char* as like as in previous example

//print to file in the same way
ofs << obj2 << foo << "string lineral followed by int\n";
```

Using `FILE` is more C than C++ but you can think how to switch between `fpirntf` and `sprintf` or use Anton's answer.

Comment: Can you please add a small code example ? I don't understand. How do I use stringstream to go from FILE* to string/char* ?

Comment: I'm talking about using `stringstream` without `FILE*`, so it's useful only if you can relinquish using `FILE*` at all. Streams are more C++ than C (more abstract), they may be easier to use and even les buggy. But as I understand, you should rewrite lots of code to use them, whereas Anton's variant is closer to your statement of question.